# does lighting:treeGrid support infinite scroll

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

The documentation references infinite scrolling as supported but I neither see the relevant attributes in the specification. Nor does the component respond when I implement it as I would for lightning datatable.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/documentation

component:

```
    <!-- infinite load--> 


    <div style="height: 200px">
        <lightning:treeGrid
            aura:id="treegrid_async"
            columns="{! v.gridColumns }"
            data="{! v.gridData }"
            expandedRows="{! v.gridExpandedRows }"
            keyField="name"
            isLoading="{! v.isLoading }"
            ontoggle="{! c.handleRowToggle }"
            enableInfiniteLoading="true"
            onloadmore="{! c.loadMore}"
        />
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

controller:

({ // eslint-disable-line

```
init: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    var columns = [
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'accountName',
            label: 'Account Name',
            initialWidth: 300
        },
        {
            type: 'number',
            fieldName: 'employees',
            label: 'Employees'
        },
        {
            type: 'phone',
            fieldName: 'phone',
            label: 'Phone Number'
        },
        {
            type: 'url',
            fieldName: 'accountOwner',
            label: 'Account Owner',
            typeAttributes: {
                label: { fieldName: 'accountOwnerName' }
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'billingCity',
            label: 'Billing City'
        }
    ];

    cmp.set('v.gridColumns', columns);

    // data
    cmp.set('v.gridData', helper.nestedData);


    var expandedRows = ["123556", "123556-B", "123557"];

    cmp.set('v.gridExpandedRows', expandedRows);
},

loadMore: function(cmp, event, helper){  
    console.log('loadedMore');
},

handleRowToggle: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    // retrieve the unique identifier of the row being expanded
    var rowName = event.getParam('name');

    // the new expanded state for this row
    var isExpanded = event.getParam('isExpanded');

    // does the component have children content for this row already?
    var hasChildrenContent = event.getParam('hasChildrenContent');

    // the complete row data
    var row = event.getParam('row');

    // the row names that are currently expanded
    var expandedRows = cmp.find('treegrid_async').getCurrentExpandedRows();

    // if hasChildrenContent is false then we need to react and add children
    if (hasChildrenContent === false) {
        cmp.set('v.isLoading', true);

        // call a method to retrieve the updated data tree that includes the missing children
        helper.retrieveUpdatedData(rowName).then(function (newData) {
            cmp.set('v.gridData', newData);
            cmp.set('v.isLoading', false);
        });
    }
}
```

}) // eslint-disable-line